# Format DateTime to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I am using EF and there is a scenario when i have to update the date from the database.

```
public DateTime? DatePosted { get; set; }
```

That is the field from the database which i have to update. But my problem is it would not update. I have a feeling that I must use the proper format using the database datetime format which is like this:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

Question is how do I force my datetime to have the same pattern as specified above? I don't want to convert it to string because it won't have the same datatype in my entity.

Comment: Is the field in the database a Datetime or a varchar?

Comment: DateTime is DateTime, so formating is not needed. SQL server might display it differently if you select it, but it's still maintaining the integrity of the value

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: database field is smalldatetime

Comment: I know now why it won't update, the field is read-only because the value is db computed. this is the mapping class:    Property(c => c.DatePosted).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed).HasColumnName("date_posted");

Answer (score 2):

it hard to answer without seeing what you are doing but typically if you just do something like 
`DatePosted=DateTime.Now;` -it should work and update your record in database.

if it does not than the problem is most like not in formatting

Comment: You are correct. It is not the formatting. The property is db computed. Will find a work around for this.

Answer (score 2):

The `DateTime` data type holds a date and time. It does not hold a formatted string.

Your problem is not with formatting. Exactly what do you mean "it would not update"?

Answer (score 2):

The database stores datetime the same no matter what(as a date and time). It is only when you cast it for output reasons that it has different formats. You should double check that your db column is set up as a datetime. That is the only reason I could see this not updating. That or you have this mapped in Ef to not update.

Otherwise, you need to post sample code of what you are trying to do